# nHibernate.Search with nHibernate v2

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, nhibernate.search

I having trouble getting nHibernate.Search to create an Index.

If I use 1.2.1.4 of nHibernate.dll & nHibernate.Search.dll then the index is created correctly and I can inspect it with Luke (a Lucene utility).
A segments file is created as well as a Fragments file etc

However, when I use v 2 of nHibernate.dll & nHibernate.Search.dll then the index is not created correctly. Only a 1k segments file is created in the Index directory and Luke is unable to inspect it.

The code I used in v1 was as follows:

```
_configuration = new Configuration();
_configuration.Configure();
_configuration.AddAssembly(typeof (Contact).Assembly);
_sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
SearchFactory.Initialize(_configuration, _sessionFactory);
```

and I have the following in the config file

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">NHibernate.Search.Storage.FSDirectoryProvider, NHibernate.Search</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">~/Index</property>
```

in version 2 there is no SearchFactory. The only similar thing I could find was

```
SearchFactoryImpl.GetSearchFactory(_configuration);
```

So I have set up the config as follows

```
_configuration = new Configuration();
_configuration.Configure();
_configuration.AddAssembly(typeof (Contact).Assembly);
_sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
_configuration.SetProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider",
                                       "NHibernate.Search.Store.FSDirectoryProvider, NHibernate.Search");

_configuration.SetProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "Index");
_configuration.SetProperty("hibernate.search.analyzer",
                                        "Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net");


_configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.PostUpdate, new FullTextIndexEventListener());
_configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.PostInsert, new FullTextIndexEventListener());
_configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.PostDelete, new FullTextIndexEventListener());

SearchFactoryImpl.GetSearchFactory(_configuration);
```

This creates the bare bones of an Index but it is not viewable with Luke - which tells me it is corrupt

I have also used the following code to try and create the index manually, but again it only creates the segments file, nothing else

```
public void CreateIndex<T>(string rootIndexDirectory)
{
    Type type = typeof (T);

    var info = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(rootIndexDirectory, type.Name));

    // Recursively delete the index and files in there
    if (info.Exists) info.Delete(true);

    // Now recreate the index
    FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(Path.Combine(rootIndexDirectory, type.Name), true);
    //Ioc.UrlProvider.MapPath(Path.Combine(rootIndexDirectory, type.Name)), true);

    try
    {
        var writer = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
        writer.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dir != null) 
            dir.Close();
    }

    using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (IFullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.CreateFullTextSession(session)) 
        {
            foreach (var contact in _contacts)
            {
                //session.Save(contact);
                fullTextSession.Index(contact);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is - do I have to use v1.1.4 of nHibernate if I want to use nHibernate.Search?
Or can I use v2? In which case what am I doing wrong?

There is very little on the web about this.

Anyone?

Comment: Someone please change the title nhibrnate to nhibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a working example here:

http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/?p=21

The v2 nHibernate.Search.dll in this project does contain a SearchFactory (albeit in a different namespace).

The one I compiled from the SVN repository doesnt have this

So all sorted